# combining outputs of two text file with awk to another file

Tags: awk

**Hello All,**
I would greatly appreciate help on this issue. 
I have two text files.

One like this:

```
int-ddr-133-20150106-1SNQ00P8T7R2I-P1-QM86FIDXJ0ZI-Partition-N5PE02B4OLQB
int-ddr-133-20150106-1SNQ00P8T7R2I-P2-1QZA0TT1XQVF9-Partition-11R1LDQI6OF9H
int-ddr-133-20150106-1SNQ00P8T7R2I-P3-1U8YDIB81O5H0-Partition-BIJC34LK49JP
```

And one like this:

```
i-370fc7d8
i-7c3cf493
i-5a1cd4b5
```

How can I create a third text file using awk to have output like this?

```
int-ddr-133-20150106-1SNQ00P8T7R2I-P1-QM86FIDXJ0ZI-Partition-N5PE02B4OLQB,i-370fc7d8
int-ddr-133-20150106-1SNQ00P8T7R2I-P2-1QZA0TT1XQVF9-Partition-11R1LDQI6OF9H,i-7c3cf493
int-ddr-133-20150106-1SNQ00P8T7R2I-P3-1U8YDIB81O5H0-Partition-BIJC34LK49JP,i-5a1cd4b5
```

Comment: I meant using AWK command not aws

Comment: Does it really have to be with awk? Seems more like a job for paste: `paste -d, f1.txt f2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print $0, a[FNR]}' file1 file2
```

but this is really a job for `paste`